# Re-render ReactDom when variable value is changed

Tags: reactjs

I'm at very begining stage in React. I want to re-render the ReactDom.render() when "loggedin" variable value is changed somehow. Say if loggedin variable value turns into true from false, the ReactDom.render() will be re-render. How can I do this? Any kind of help will be appreciated. The code snippet is here-

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import AuthLayout from "layouts/Auth.js";
import RtlLayout from "layouts/RTL.js";
import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin.js";

import "assets/scss/material-dashboard-pro-react.scss?v=1.9.0";

import { Component } from 'react'
import AdminLogin from "views/Signup-Login/AdminLogin";


let loggedin = false

class Index extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  
    this.state = {
       isLoggedin: false
    }    
  }
  
  LoginStatusHandler = (isLoggedinValue) =>{
    alert(isLoggedinValue);
    this.setState({
      isLoggedin: isLoggedinValue
    })
    loggedin = isLoggedinValue;
  }

  render() {

    const {isLoggedin} = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        {(() => {
          if (isLoggedin === false) {
            return <AdminLogin LoginStatusChange={this.LoginStatusHandler}/>;
          }
        })()}        
    </div>
    )
  }
}

//export default Index



const hist = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  
  <Router history={hist}>
    {console.log(loggedin)}
    {loggedin?
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/rtl" component={RtlLayout} />
      <Route path="/auth" component={AuthLayout} />
      <Route path="/admin" component={AdminLayout} />
      <Redirect from="/" to="/admin/dashboard" />
    </Switch> : <Index />}
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Comment: use State variables instead of plain javascript variable. When state changes, react will  rerender the component automatically

Comment: Correct, the `loggedin` value should be part of *some* component's state. React components are pretty simple in this regard, they rerender when state and/or props update. If you could provide a more comprehensive [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) we may be able to provide more targeted suggestions.

Comment: Dear @DrewReese Thanks for your nice suggestion. Actually I want to login my system APP. After Login from the child component, the parent component(index.js) will update the status of loggedin. Then based on the successful login and status update the ReactDom.render() should re-render. Can you help me regarding this. I've updated my code in the description section.

Comment: You seem to be missing a few React basics. I would recommend reading [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and then also recommend you reconsider the code structure. It appears you are wanting to render certain routes only when authenticated. Switching out the entire React app tree there at the root splits where the `isLoggedin` state can be used. See [Auth Workflow](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow). If you still need assistance from here let me know.

Comment: Thank you dear @DrewReese for your nice support. I've solved the problem as per your suggestion. You can check the below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import AuthLayout from "layouts/Auth.js";
import RtlLayout from "layouts/RTL.js";
import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin.js";

import "assets/scss/material-dashboard-pro-react.scss?v=1.9.0";

import AdminLogin from "views/Signup-Login/AdminLogin";

const hist = createBrowserHistory();    

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
      
        this.state = {
           isLoggedin: false
        }    
      }
      
      LoginStatusHandler = (isLoggedinValue) =>{
        //alert(isLoggedinValue);
        this.setState({
          isLoggedin: isLoggedinValue
        })
      }
    
      render() {
    
        const {isLoggedin} = this.state
    
        return (
          <div>
            {
              isLoggedin === false ? 
                <AdminLogin LoginStatusChange={this.LoginStatusHandler}/>
                :
                (<Router history={hist}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/rtl" component={RtlLayout} />
                        <Route path="/auth" component={AuthLayout} />
                        <Route path="/admin" component={AdminLayout} />
                        <Redirect from="/" to="/admin/dashboard" />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>)
            }       
        </div>
        )
      }
}

export default App
```